# Change Regional Settings for all users in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

How do I change date format Regional Settings for all users in Windows Server 2012 that is not a domain controller? I also want to change "Language for non-Unicode programs" for all users. Since this is not a domain controller, the users are defined in "Computer Management/Users" and not in Active Directory.

The only answers I found were for domain controllers (http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/08/16/how-to-change-regional-settings-for-all-users-on-a-computer.aspx).

It would be great if there was a way to check the settings for a specific user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So - I am assuming you are wanting to do this on more than one machine across a network.

Logon scripts would be the way and you can change the registry setting by running a reg file from the script.

the registry setting is

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International.

there is an MS blog on this [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/08/16/how-to-change-regional-settings-for-all-users-on-a-computer.aspx)

Which you have already referenced, this explains the Group Policy way AND the registry way.
So if you run a script whenever you log on to that machine.

Simply put the logon script in a folder and point to it from the users profile in computer management.

local users

choose a user, right click properties, profile tab enter the logon script in the box and hey presto.

plenty of online help for how to create a reg file and how to create a logon script.

shout if you need answers on that.

Comment: I want to do this for multiple users on a single machine that is running Windows Server 2012. The users access the server via RDP. **Thanks** for pointing out that the TechNet link shows the registry method. I am assuming that the registry method will work on a standalone server that is not part of a domain. I am going to apply the registry settings as shown here [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Easily-set-a-registry-b3449784)

Comment: absolutely yes you can use logon script for all users (SAME SCRIPT) and then it will work fine.

Comment: don't forget to mark it as the correct answer (vote!) cheers